# Llenar tabla footlable con JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

Buenas tardes, Estoy intentando llenar una tabla con JSON, la tabla es de clase footable, pero no me aparecen los datos en la tabla, este es mi codigo:

```js
$('#tUsuarios').footable({
rows:[{"Email":"andres@hotmail.com","PrimerNombre":"Andres","Rol":"Administrador"}],
          columns:[
            {"data":"", "name":""},
            {"data":"Email", "name":"Email"},
            {"data":"PrimerNombre", "name":"Primer Nombre"},
            {"data":"Rol", "name":"Rol"}   
        ]       
            });
```

```html
<table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="3" id="tUsuarios">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Correo</th>
                                        <th>Nombre</th>
                                        <th>Rol</th>
                                    </tr>
                                        
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

Comment: No se muestran todos o alguna columna ?  el `name`  para la tercera columna es `PrimerNombre`  **sin espacios**.

Comment: @afar1793 Lo que miro es que no relacionas tus datos con la consulta

Comment: @RaulCacacho Hola gracias, cuando uso dataTable en lugar de footable, y ademas reemplazando rows por data, si me funciona, como puedo relacionar los datos con las consultas para un footable?